# Ruby - Webpacker can't find application in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rubygems

After installing the device gem, I encountered an error. How can i fix this:

```
Webpacker can't find application in /home/grkmdgn06/Desktop/my5_homework/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

Extracted source (around line #9):
...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> # error line
```

...

Answer (score 3):

perhaps your node.js is out of date

try this:

```sh
sudo npm install n -g

sudo n stable

bundle exec rake webpacker:install
```